# define perforce plugin in sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

i'm trying to define perforce plugin version 1.2 in SonarQube version 5.2.
According to below instructions:
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Perforce+Plugin
i have defined below parameters in sonar.properties file:
`sonar.perforce.port
sonar.perforce.username
sonar.perforce.password.secured`

i have restarted the sonar service and open log file to see if i have errors - no error shown.

i defined SonarQube to send me mail in case in some project i have issues.
till now, i didn't have way to look in the mail and see who insert the new code which cause the issue. only way to do it is to go to the SonarQube link in the mail, look for the files changed and then open perforce to see who is the last one changed the file and send him mail.
i wanted that perforce plugin will automate this and in the mail i get from SonarQube, the relevant changelist in Perforce will shown.

Is anyone knows if the plugin support this?
If no, what can i do with the plugin? how it can help me?

Thanks,
Idan.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you pass `sonar.scm.provider=perforce` like mentioned [in documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Perforce+Plugin). I also encourage you to use freshly released version 1.3 of the Perforce plugin.

Comment: Hi, i have added this var to the sonar.properties file and also upgraded plugin to version 1.3. i'm still facing issues i mentioned before in the original question. Can you please let me know what the plugin do? what i need to expect when it is defined as in documentation?

Comment: The plugin will collect "annotate" data during project analysis (ie for each line of source file: author, changelog id, changelog date). This data will be displayed in SonarQube UI in the left margin of each source file. Blame date will be used to determine what is new code (for all metrics "on new code") and blame author will be used to assign issues to the right person (auto-assign feature).

Comment: Hi, when i click on filename in the GUI, i'm getting the code with all the issues (for each line). at the left side i don't see any info, as you mention, about author, changelog id, changelog date. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because the blame was not properly collected during project analysis. Please share logs.

Comment: Analysis logs (sonar-runner / mvn sonar:sonar / whatever scanner you are using to trigger the analysis)

Comment: Reading your question again I saw "sonar.properties". Are you trying to put those analysis properties in server configuration file? If yes then that's your issue. Analysis properties should be passed to the scanner, not to the server.

Comment: Yes, i putted the configuration in sonar.properties file. How can i know who is my scanner? where is this defined? I'm really new in Sonar and I'm trying to get the full picture.

Comment: Hi Julien, i have checked and all 3 parts of sonar are installed on the same server (DB, analyzer and web GUI). is that can cause issue? another question, in the perforce plugin jar, i saw an exe file. it means that it can be run only on windows?

Comment: The exe file is a mistake (copy/paste from TFVS plugin) but not used at all. Thanks for the notification. The plugin is using p4java library that is cross platform.

Comment: what about first part of my question?

Comment: Having all components on the same host is not an issue. Please edit your question to provide more details: what is the SonarQube Scanner you are using (for Maven ? SonarQube Runner? Ant ? Gradle?) and part of analysis logs where you see SCM Sensor execution like here: https://travis-ci.org/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-cli/jobs/102059326#L585